# Android spinner - change arrow icon but keep bottom border

Tags: android

I have a spinner with bottom line

```
    <Spinner
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

But when I change a arrow icon apliyng the new style

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_arrow</item>
</style>
```

My bottom line disappears.
How to change arrow icon and keep bottom line?

Comment: Create custom spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ĝüptå Šhãsĥwæt for a answer, here is a full working drawable for API 21+

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="-2dp"
                android:right="-2dp"
                android:top="-2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#80909c"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item >
                <bitmap
                    android:gravity="right" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>

    <layer-list>


        <item>
            <bitmap

                android:gravity="right" android:src="@drawable/spinnerr" />
        </item>
        <item android:width="650dp" android:height="1dp" android:gravity="bottom">

            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDarker" />
                <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>

</item>
```

create a drawable background and setas background the bitmap used in this drawable is your down arrow image

Comment: item android:width is available only since API 23

Comment: But for me that drawable fills whole spinner area with a dark color

Comment: May be ur drawable is in bigger size,  try to use smaller image